# How to best work around elderly cat not using litter box?

Tags: cats, senior-pet

So our elderly cat, who is around 17, sometimes "forgets" about the litter box.

He is generally rather confused at times and his senses are not the best.
He urinates and defecates other places at times, but sometimes also uses the litter box. I do not think that this is a training issue, since it feels like he is just too old and seems to have something I would call dementia in people.

So what are your ideas to either prevent those accidents or at least to have easier clean up?

What we tried so far:

1. As a suggestion from our vet, we tried painkillers in case the issue was arthritis
2. We put out more litter boxes (and some different ones)
3. We also put out some pads around the boxes, but he does not just miss, he sometimes goes somewhere else entirely

Of course, we have been cleaning the places he goes diligently, as not to encourage him to go there again. What did you have success with, or what are ideas you have to make it less of a clean-up hassle?

EDIT: Answers to comments

Yes, we have tried a bigger one, with a very low entrance. He uses it, but only as well (or not) as the others.

He does not usually go where we see him.

Yes, we have stared to limit his access to the house during nighttime because finding every spot in the morning was turning into detective work.

Comment: Have you tried litter boxes for old/disabled cats?  Such as https://www.chewy.com/shirley-ks-senior-cat-litter-box-x/dp/335080. They are designed to have a very low entrance for easy access.  Also bigger is better because as a senior cat he may have trouble turning around.

Comment: Does he use areas that aren't his litterbox while you're watching him? Or only when you're not around? If you see him start to go, are you able to move him to a litterbox or pee pad successfully when you see him start? Sometimes it's best to confine an elderly cat to one room/space when you're not able to supervise both for cleaning ease and for his own safety

Comment: I know one family that just resigned themselves to having to clean up after an elderly cat, and another which confined the cat to an area with tiled floors when there wasn't someone there to supervise but tried to spend time in that area to keep the cat company.. In the end it's a matter of quality of life -- the animal's, and yours.